# Atom update hangs inside of Clojure watch call

Tags: clojure, filesystems, atomic-swap

I've got a [situation](https://github.com/Inaimathi/langnostic/blob/master/src/langnostic/posts.clj#L10-L25) where I watch a specific directory for filesystem changes. If a certain file in that directory is changed, I re-read it, attach some existing cached information, and store it in an `atom`.

The relevant code looks like

```
(def posts (atom []))

(defn load-posts! []
  (swap!
   posts
   (fn [old]
     (vec
      (map #(let [raw (json/parse-string % (fn [k] (keyword (.toLowerCase k))))]
              (<snip some processing of raw, including getting some pieces from old>))
           (line-seq (io/reader "watched.json")))))))


;; elsewhere, inside of -main
(watch/start-watch
    [{:path "resources/"
      :event-types [:modify]
      :callback (fn [event filename]
                  (when (and (= :modify event) (= "watched.json" filename))
                    (println "Reloading posts.json ...")
                    (posts/load-posts!)))}
     ...])
```

This ends up working fine locally, but when I deploy it to my server, the `swap!` call hangs about half-way through.

I've tried debugging it via `println`, which told me

1. The filesystem trigger *is* being fired.
2. `swap!` is not running the function more than once
3. The watched file is being opened and parsed
4. Some entries from the file are being processed, but that processing stops at entry `111` (which doesn't seem to be significantly different from any preceding entries).
5. The update does not complete, and the old value of that `atom` is therefore preserved
6. No filesystem events are fired after this one hangs.

I suspect that this is either a memory issue somewhere, or possibly a bug in [Clojure-Watch](https://github.com/derekchiang/Clojure-Watch) (or the underlying FS-watching library).

Any ideas how I might go about fixing it or diagnosing it further?

Comment: Seems likely that an error is occurring during processing that is getting swallowed. Turn the in-line function being mapped onto the line-seq into separate individual functions and test them on the relevant entry.

Comment: ... or put a try/catch around the call to `load-posts!` and see what's getting thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hang is caused by an error being thrown inside of the function passed as a `:callback` to `watch/start`.

The root cause in this case is that the modified file is being copied to the server by `scp` (which is not atomic, and the first event therefore triggers before the copy is complete, which is what causes the JSON parse error to be thrown).

This is exacerbated by the fact that `watch/start` fails silently if its `:callback` throws any kind of error.

The solutions here are

1. Use `rsync` to copy files. It does copy atomically **but** it will not generate any `:modify` events on the target file, only related temp-files. Because of the way its atomic copy works, it will **only** signal `:create` events.
2. Wrap the `:callback` in a `try`/`catch`, and have the `catch` clause return the old value of the atom. This will cause `load-posts!` to run multiple times, but the last time will be on file copy completion, which should finally do the right thing.

(I've done both, but either would have realistically solved the problem).

A third option would be using an FS-watching library that reports errors, such as [Hawk](https://github.com/wkf/hawk) or [dirwatch](https://github.com/juxt/dirwatch) (or possibly [hara.io.watch](http://docs.caudate.me/hara/hara-io-watch.html)? I haven't used any of these, so I can't comment).

Diagnosing this involved wrapping the `:callback` body with

```
(try 
  <body> 
  (catch Exception e 
    (println "ERROR IN SWAP!" e) 
    old))
```

to see what was actually being thrown. Once that printed a JSON parsing error, it was pretty easy to gain a theory of what was going wrong.

Comment: Couple of comments on the answer- scp makes no attempt to be atomic, but rsync does. See http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769263/are-rsync-operations-atomic-at-file-level#6903839. So one can often watch for the "create" event, which is fired when rsync performs the mv of a temporary direntry to the permanent one.

Comment: The start-watch function returns a future, but it wasn't being dereferenced. There are two other active watch projects, hawk and dirwatch; both of those appear to .printStackTrace any exceptions instead.

Comment: @JonahB - I started with `rsync`, but switched to `scp` because I wasn't seeing `:modify` events with it. I'll test to see if the `:create` event gets picked up, and update my answer if it does (that way requires a lot less hacking around).

Comment: Gotcha, it sounds like there is a workflow? That perhaps the processed posts and other files should be deleted on the receipt side after processing?

Comment: @JonahB - Kinda? It's a very minimal blog engine I wrote for myself. What I want is to be able to just copy `md`/`json` files up to my server and get them published without mucking about with restarting a server. The idea is that this manages cached posts by watching what files change. This entire thing could be avoided by using a static-file middleware for `http-kit`, I just wanted to write it myself. And yes, watching for `:create` signals from `rsync` works perfectly.